# AWS IAM Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have used AWS IAM Authentication in my API to authorize each request. Now I want the User Name of the authenticated request of the users. For example, one user makes a request to my API and he is already authorized(IAM Entry) then I want the user name or API key of that user. Have any idea?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use IAM Authentication instead of Amazon Cognito for Authentication?

Answer (score 3):

I just did a test for you. The lambda received the following event.

```
{
  ...
  "body": null,
  "resource": "/",
  "requestContext": {
    "identity": {
      "userArn": "arn:aws:iam::561819318197:user/testadmin",
      "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
      "principalOrgId": null,
      "accessKey": "AKIAABTYKO625OKJWL65",
      "caller": "AIDAYFTYKO62TO35WYOWZ",
      "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0",
      "user": "AIDAYFTCDO62TO35WYOWZ",
      "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
      "cognitoIdentityId": null,
      "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
      "sourceIp": "[user ip]",
      "accountId": "123456789012"
    },
    "accountId": "123456789012"
  }
  ...
}
```

I think you can use the `event.requestContext.user`.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Yes, but I am getting in a string like 

`%7B%22resource%22%3A%22%2F%7Bproxy%2B%7D%22%2C%22path%22%3A%22%2Fapim%2Fv1%2FgetWebhook%2Frajspatel1297%40gmail.com%22%2C%22httpMethod%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22Accept%22%3A%22*%2F*%22%2C%22Accept-Encoding%22%3A%22gzip%2C%20deflate%2C%20br%22%2C%22Cache-Control%22%3A%22no-cache%22%2C%22Content-Type%22%3A%22application%2Fjson%22%2C%22Host%22%3A%22api.diaspofinance.com%22%2C%22Postman-Token%22%3A%2236175049-dec3-468e-8c0f-42c75f6de9fe%22%2C%22User-Agent%22%3A%22PostmanRuntime%2F7.22.`



Why?. I am using Lambda proxy.

Comment: How are you sending this request

Comment: Using Postman AWS Signature Option and set AccessKey and SecretKey

Comment: You select the AWS signature under authorization right. I'm talking about the body of the request. The postman let's you select "FormData" , raw and etc. Also are you setting the content type as "application/json"